# Linear model on decompose time series in R and interpretation

Tags: r, time-series, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients, trend

I am a newbie in time series.
I need a help with an interpretation of simple example of time series.

I would like to analyze whether trends over time of time series significantly increases/decreases independently from seasonal and random effects(H0: trends does not significantly increase).
Firstly, I want to decompose the time series "AirPassengers". 
Time is indexed as natural numbers. Finally, I use linear model regression and assess coef, se and p-value.

Let's see the code:

```
library(lmtest)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
###SIMPLE EXAMPLE
data(AirPassengers)
d <- decompose(AirPassengers) 
t <- melt(d$trend)
```

Here's is plot of `d$trend`
[image]

```
t <- t%>% drop_na(value)
t$time<-c(1:nrow(t)) 
linear<-lm(value ~time, data=t)
coeftest(linear)


t test of coefficients:

              Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 100.649901   1.919275  52.442 < 2.2e-16 ***
time          2.666938   0.025042 106.500 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

cor(t$value,predict(linear))
[1] 0.994318
```

I interpret the outcome as significant (p<0.05) increase of the variable over analyzed period. Is it correct?  Shall I used another model?

Answer (score 0):

The residuals from your model will suggest possible augmentations.

[image]

Ultimately your final model will be

[image]

.....thus future values are expected to be 80% of the most recent plus 100% of the value 12 periods ago minus 80% of the value 13 periods ago PLUS 6.56 . Thus the forecast is quite dependent on seasonal factors i.e. what occurred 12 & 13 periods ago.

[image]

A linear regression with TIME as a predictor is inadequate as the growth is stochastic (adaptive) not deterministic (fixed)

EDITED IN RESPONSE TO OP'S COMMENTS:

Use https://autobox.com/pdfs/SARMAX.pdf as the objective following https://autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA%20FLOW%20CHART.pdf as outlined in [https://www.amazon.com/Time-Analysis-Univariate-Multivariate-1989-01-01/dp/B01K0U13EQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01K0U13EQ) and elsewhere .

Comment: I have added plot and correlation of the model and d$trend. So what kind of modeling should I use to get the answer whether trend increases/decreases significantly?

Comment: the series is forecasted to increase over last year's values which may or not be greater than 2 year's before that.

Comment: Is it rational to alternatively use Mann Kendal Trend test (https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/mann-kendall-trend-test/) to estimate whether trend is signifificant?

Comment: I don't know anything about this non-parametric test . I will let others respond. Non-parametric tests are often the last resort when you have messy data ,